# Double-linked List find the element nearest to the average

Tags: algorithm

There is a **sorted double-linked list**（C++ STL std::list）, e.g., "1,1,2,3,4,5,6", and how to find the element that is nearest to the average of the list by scanning once?(the nearest element to the average 22/7 is 3)

Comment: Is it important? 2*n is still O(n)

Comment: It's an interview question, and the interviewer says the list is very long, so he may expect to scan it just once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key here is that it's a double-linked-list.

What you need to do is go from both sides at the same time, calculating the average as you go.

If the average so far is more than the right iterator's element, increase the left iterator.

If the average is less than the left iterator's element, decrease the right iterator.

If the average is between the two, move either or both inward (let's say we move the left one).

When the iterators meet, stop. Look at the current element, and the elements one back and one forward to see which is closest.

**Why this works:**

If the average is less than the left value, it could stay less, so that element (or the one one position to the left) could be the closest, thus we mustn't move that iterator.

If the average is greater than the left value, since all elements not yet processed are greater than the left value, it's impossible for the average to drop below the left value, thus we can safely increase the left iterator. More technically, the left value can still be the closest, but not the value one position to the left (which is why we need to look at the surrounding elements). Look at the increase of 3 to 4 below as an example.

Similarly for the right value.

**Example:**

```
1,1,2,3,4,5,6  Average
L           R  7/2 = 3.5
  L         R  8/3 = 2.667
    L       R  10/4 = 2.5
      L     R  13/5 = 2.6
      L   R    18/6 = 3
        L R    22/7 = 3.14
        LR
```

Then looking at 3,4 and 5, we see 3 is the closest.

Comment: Cool answer. A way to make your argument clearer is to apply induction. Your argument/invariant might be something like "let D be the double linked list, let L and R be the pointers. At any point in the algorithm, L points at D[i] and R points at D[j] we have the invariant that L[i] or L[i-1] is the closest to the average _so far_ and symmetrically for R[j] or R[j+1]". And then at the end you have three elements to inspect, L[i-1], L[i] = R[j], R[j+1].

Comment: I got how you operate it, and I have one more question: when L and R meets, there is three circumstances: 1) avg < L, 2) avg == L or avg == R, 3) avg > R, so how will you operate, continue to scan from L to the  left for 1) and continue to scan from R to the right for 2)?

Comment: @JavaBeta If `avg < L`, just return whichever one between `L-1` or `L` is closer to the average. If `avg > R`, do the same with `R` and `R+1`. You only need to look one position back / forward because of the argument provided under "Why this works".

Comment: My example has some problem, the avg > 1 actually, but it could explain my doubts.

Comment: 1,100,100,100,1000 is a possible example

Comment: @JavaBeta Do you mean something like `...,1,2,2,2,2,2,...` where 1 is closest to the average, but `L` and `R` meet somewhere in the middle of the 2's? This can't happen because once you get to the first 2, you'll never move to the next 2 as long as the average is less than 2. If the average is more than 2, any element you'll include from there will be 2 or more, thus including it in the average can't cause it to drop below 2. `1,100,100,100,1000` will end up with L and R on 1000, thus it will look at 100 and 1000 and 100 will be chosen.

Comment: What if there's no reference to the last element in the list, would it still be possible to do it scanning once?

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves No, I don't believe it will be possible.

Comment: @Dukeling Are we assuming that its a circular doubly linked list because otherwise it would take one traversal just to find the last element in the list?

Comment: @Kunal Not circular, but I am assuming we have a reference to the last element (which you generally have with double-linked-lists).